# "I have done something so that there was" or "I have done something so that there was"?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

Could you tell me which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> I have cropped the picture so that there **is** all your body in it.
>
> I have cropped the picture so that there **was** all your body in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, but the issue here isn't grammar. A native speaker would phrase these statements differently.

This sounds more natural, but is still a bit vague:

> I cropped the picture so that all of your body is in it.

for more clarity, you can say something like this:

> I cropped the picture so that it contains your entire body

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you explaine one more thing. We are tought that tenses have to agree. In your example they do not. Shouldn't be "I cropped the picture so that all of your body was in it"?

Comment: "cropped" refers to something you did in the past, whereas the body being in the picture refers to the state of the picture *now*, not as it was before you cropped it. To illustrate why using the present tense is correct, it's equivalent to say: "I cropped the picture so that it *now* contains your entire body". Tenses would have to agree if you said "I cropped and edited the picture". "I cropped and edit the picture." would be incorrect.